# Sort on a WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, rollup

I can do the following fine:

```
SELECT provider_id, count(*) cnt 
FROM title 
GROUP BY provider_id WITH ROLLUP
```

However, it doesn't seem to support ordering after a rollup:

```
SELECT provider_id, count(*) cnt 
FROM title 
GROUP BY provider_id WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

> Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Two questions related to this:

1. Are you not allowed to use an `order by` in the same select statement as a `with rollup`? Or, is this something specific to mysql5.7 -- in that it doesn't support this feature -- but other DBs do dupport this?
2. Given this constraint, is the only way to do the sort by using a subselect?

   ```
   SELECT * FROM  (<rollup query>) _ ORDER BY cnt DESC
   ```

---

Related, but doesn't really answer the above question (as I already have the query above): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768565/651174.

Comment: which mysql version are you using 8.0.22 seems to have no problem with it.

Comment: @nbk -- 5.7.... (Maybe that answers my first question -- that it's part of the sql standard but just not supported by mysql < 8)

Comment: the documentation states that 5.7.32 has it also

Comment: @nbk -- ah, ok. Actually I'm one off, sorry about that: `select version() 5.6.44-log`

Comment: @nbk could you please share the link where it says which version supports it?

Comment: you have to read the maual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html but there is also written that it is supported

Comment: but it is only supported in mysql 8 correctly sorry see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8205e515bf29427973902a3f216457f  prior versions give the same error

Comment: Versions prior to 8.0 does not support ORDER BY COUNT(*) in shown case, and subquery is the only option. Version 8+ allows such sorting. It seems that ROLLUP in those ancient version acts over final (and already sorted!) rowset (like window functions)

Comment: @Akina I see -- want to post in an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: "Previously, MySQL did not allow the use of DISTINCT or ORDER BY in a query having a WITH ROLLUP option. This restriction is lifted in MySQL 8.0.12 and later. (Bug #87450, Bug #86311, Bug #26640100, Bug #26073513)" ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html#:~:text=The%20GROUP%20BY%20clause%20permits,analysis%20with%20a%20single%20query.))